# Finally executes before last `.then` when using chained promises

Tags: node.js, promise, rsvp.js

How come my last .then (**writeLin..**) doesn't run?

Note: `triggercommand` returns function that returns promise

```
 .then(function () {

    if (fs.existsSync(tempDir + '/' + repoName)) {
      return self.triggerCommand("git", ["checkout", "master"], {cwd: tempDir + '/' + repoName})()
        .then(
        self.triggerCommand("git", ["pull", "master"], {cwd: tempDir + '/' + repoName})
      )
    }
    return self.triggerCommand("git", ["clone", remote], {cwd: tempDir});
  }
)

  .then(
    writeLine("Git clone/pull complete.")//this never runs
)

.finally(function () {
    //this runs
```

Comment: Why are you calling `existsSync` inside a promise chain?

Comment: In the case of `fs.existsSync` being true - you're calling the triggerCommand and not waiting for it instead of waiting for the promise. (need to wrap it in a function).

Comment: why can't I call in the chain?

Comment: `then` takes a function.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yeah but fs.existsSync is called in a function..

Comment: This: `.then(
        self.triggerCommand("git", ["pull", "master"], {cwd: tempDir + '/' + repoName})`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I add `() `to that command (checkout  master) so I can chain a .then to it.. the git pull one, sorry this stuff is a bit hard for me to follow

Comment: can you put your code in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Promises](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) spec, the `then` function should **receive a function** that will be called whenever the promise is resolved.

Your `writeLine("Git clone/pull complete.")` will run in the moment the `then` chain is configured, because it is **not wrapped in a function**.

The fix is simple enough:

```
.then(function () {
    if (fs.existsSync(tempDir + '/' + repoName)) {
      return self.triggerCommand("git", ["checkout", "master"], {cwd: tempDir + '/' + repoName})()
        .then(
        self.triggerCommand("git", ["pull", "master"], {cwd: tempDir + '/' + repoName})
      )
    }
    return self.triggerCommand("git", ["clone", remote], {cwd: tempDir});
  }
)
.then(function(){
  writeLine("Git clone/pull complete.")
})
.finally(function () {
    //this runs
})
```